# How can I use NumberPicker.CustomEditText in code

Tags: android

I am trying to change text color of my timePicker and I reached this child

```
NumberPicker.CustomEditText
```

but I cannot use this class and I got this error

```
NumberPicker.CustomEditText cannot be resolved to a type
```

Comment: it is a private class - not in public API

Comment: Hey, the complete StackTrace would be usefull and also the code where you uses this code-fragment could be usefull to solve your problem. Greets

Comment: I see that it is public static class CustomEditText extends EditText